# mariadb sluggish after drop table

Tags: mariadb, innodb, galera

I am running galera cluster (mariadb) with 2 nodes.
We had one very large history table that I dropped and recreated only the structure for it from a mysqldump
ever since then the database has been getting more and more sluggish.

Do I need to reboot my sql server cluster?  Is the RAM still populated with history table data?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably have been faster to do `TRUNCATE TABLE`.  This would keep the structure but remove the data.

`DROP TABLE` has a delayed overhead on most Operating Systems.  The OS spends some time freeing up the pieces of the file that represents that table.  For 'small' tables this effort goes unnoticed.  For a huge table, it may take minutes.

As for "more and more" sluggish, this could be a compounding of things being slowed down, then interfering with each other.  Did you also note a large rise in `Threads_running`?

You may need to keep an eye on the slowlog to see what queries are sensitive to this kind of interference.  Then work on speeding up the slowest.

Comment: truncate makes a copy of the table before dropping, right? a temporary one?  I did not have the drive space left to do that. Also, truncate takes a lot longer than drop if the table is messy, right?

Comment: by the way, used your suggestion and did track down some problems with requests from another machine.  rebooting its network switch seemed to clear things up a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @shawnbright - Drive space is not an issue.  Think of it as `CREATE TABLE t LIKE main; DROP TABLE main; RENAME TABLE t TO main;`  Caution:  `FOREIGN KEYs` may have some hiccups.

Comment: very cool, thanks very much.. optimize uses the temp table, right. did not know this about truncate. this helps

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost never useful.  And, yes, it involves copying the table over.  `ANALYZE TABLE` recomputes the 'statistics' quickly and without any extra disk space.